# PHP does not catch Exception (namespace)

Tags: php, exception, frameworks, namespaces, nested

to sum it up: I've got an exception-class (\core\exceptions\GuruMeditationException) that extends from \Exception. Every other exception class simply extends from my own exception class.
When my code runs and an exception is thrown everything works perfect for me.

Now:
Assume I have a class (\app\HomeView) that extends from \core\base\mvc\View. Exceptions thrown in there are caught fine, too. The class declaration looks like this:

```
namespace app;
class HomeView extends \core\base\mvc\View {
}
```

But:
If I do the following:

```
namespace app;
class HomeView extends \core\base\mvc\DoesNotExist {   # line 5
}
```

then no exception is caught anymore.
I've already tried to catch *all* exceptions i created, with and without namespace. I also tried to catch 'Exception' and '\Exception' but nothing will help.
Instead I get an error similar to that:

```
Fatal error: Class 'core\base\mvc\DoesNotExistView' not found in /var/www/abuhome/htdocs/test-namespace/class/HomeView.class.php on line 5

Call Stack:
0.0001     635104   1. {main}() /var/www/abuhome/htdocs/test-namespace/index.php:0
0.0135    1536280   2. core\Quantum->make() /var/www/abuhome/htdocs/test-namespace/index.php:36
0.0135    1540880   3. core\scriptlet\ProtocolScriptlet->dispatch() /home/equinox/qf-namespace/class/Quantum.class.php:124
0.0136    1540880   4. core\scriptlet\XhtmlScriptlet->dispatch() /home/equinox/qf-namespace/class/scriptlet/ProtocolScriptlet.class.php:39
0.0136    1540880   5. core\template\tpl\TplContainerParser->parseContainerFile() /home/equinox/qf-namespace/class/scriptlet/XhtmlScriptlet.class.php:22
0.0139    1564656   6. core\scriptlet\ContentScriptlet->executeSuitingRequestParameter() /home/equinox/qf-namespace/class/template/tpl/TplContainerParser.class.php:42
0.0139    1564656   7. core\scriptlet\ContentScriptlet->processMainContent() /home/equinox/qf-namespace/class/scriptlet/ContentScriptlet.class.php:145
0.0141    1573640   8. core\scriptlet\ContentScriptlet->processModule() /home/equinox/qf-namespace/class/scriptlet/ContentScriptlet.class.php:154
0.0143    1583808   9. include('/var/www/abuhome/htdocs/test-namespace/modules/home.php') /home/equinox/qf-namespace/class/scriptlet/ContentScriptlet.class.php:174
0.0143    1584248  10. uses() /var/www/abuhome/htdocs/test-namespace/modules/home.php:4
0.0151    1637696  11. require_once('/var/www/abuhome/htdocs/test-namespace/class/HomeView.class.php') /home/equinox/qf-namespace/functions/uses.function.php:49
```

Can anyone help me please? I think I've forgot something, but I can't figure out what it is >.<

thank you

Comment: @Phil The edit button is right there below the question...

Comment: @Juhana I'd rather Tristan learn from my comment

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cannot catch or stop fatal errors, they are fatal.

A syntax error is not an exceptional circumstance.

Comment: hum ok. I don't think this is a syntax error - fatal, ok - but in my opinion this should be catchable =/

Comment: @TristanCebulla You can catch it via an autoloader if you really, really want to ;)

Comment: @TristanCebulla Perhaps "syntax error" is not entirely accurate. More of a compilation / parse error

Comment: i already have an autoloader (the uses() function), but that does not prevent from fatal typing errors when extending from a nonexistant class. or is there some namespace/autoload-magic i don't know?

Comment: @TristanCebulla What do you hope to achieve by catching an error like this? Your code can obviously not continue to be parsed as compilation will be impossible

Comment: intentionally i just want to see that i've tried to extend from a class that does not exist. well, sure i see that including a stacktrace, but to have it via my exception class would be nice. 

but however, i'll just accept the facts now and start thinking before typing ;) thank you all ^^